# Slicing inner index of a pandas Hierarchical Index throws a keyerror

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do sql-style query on a pandas hierarchical-index dataframe.  The level(0) index is 'Exercise' and level(1) is 'Date' a datetime.  I can happily slice if I specify a value for the level(o) index.

> print gbed.loc['Bench', pd.to_datetime('2011-01-03')]

but if I try to use a colon to represent "all rows" for the level(0) index,  the slice fails with a keyerror on the level(1)

```
# KeyError: 'the label [2011-01-03 00:00:00] is not in the [columns]'
print gbed.loc[:, pd.to_datetime('2011-01-03')]
```

The Visualizing Pandas book suggests this inner-indexing is possible *in some cases* but I cannot figure out when/why it doesn't work.

> ```
> Selection is even possible in some cases from an “inner” level:
> In [267]: data[:, 2]
> Out[267]:
> a 0.852965
> ```

From Page 147 of 'Python for Data Analysis'

Am wondering if I'm specifying the slice incorrectly in the last case?  The example code is below.

```
import pandas as pd
#make an index with a handful of duplicate dates
dates1 = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=8, freq='D')
dates2 = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=4, freq='D')
dates = dates1.append(dates2)

ex = ['Squat','Squat','Squat','Squat','Squat','Squat','Squat','Squat','Bench','Bench','Bench','Bench',]
wt = [100,120,140,150,150,140,160,172,90,90,100,110]
cols = {'Exercise': ex, 'Weight': wt, 'Date': dates}

sf = pd.DataFrame(cols)

gbed = sf.groupby(['Exercise','Date']).max()
print gbed

#These two work: return rows for a specific exercise on 2011-01-03
# SELECT * WHERE Exercise = 'Bench' AND  Date = 2011-01-03
print gbed.loc['Bench', pd.to_datetime('2011-01-03')]
print gbed.loc['Squat', pd.to_datetime('2011-01-03')]

#I am trying to return all rows that have a dated of '2011-01-03'
# SELECT * WHERE Date = 2011-01-03
# KeyError: 'the label [2011-01-03 00:00:00] is not in the [columns]'
print gbed.loc[:, pd.to_datetime('2011-01-03')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selecting by `MultiIndex` use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) or [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers), which are nice for complicated selecting:

```
print (gbed.xs('2011-01-03', level=1, axis=0))
          Weight
Exercise        
Bench        100
Squat        140

print (gbed.xs('2011-01-03', level=1, axis=0, drop_level=False))
                     Weight
Exercise Date              
Bench    2011-01-03     100
Squat    2011-01-03     140

idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (gbed.loc[idx[:, '2011-01-03'], :])
                     Weight
Exercise Date              
Bench    2011-01-03     100
Squat    2011-01-03     140

idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (gbed.loc[idx['Bench', '2011-01-03'], :])
                     Weight
Exercise Date              
Bench    2011-01-03     100
```